# add-opens does not see the dependent module

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, java-module

When trying to run spring boot app packaged as jar file with dependencies, --add-opens does not see module comming from dependecy, but it does see the spring-core.

I'm trying to figure out how to make dependencies visible for add-opens?

When I run this with IDE it all works, but IDE runs the thing with all dependencies listed with -classpath

I've tried changing config of spring-boot-maven-plugin but no success so far.

Comment: You've got to share a minimal reproducible question. The question is not at all clear as to what is it that you are facing a challenge with.

Comment: When the dependencies are provided through the class path, there are no module names. You’d need to specify `ALL-UNNAMED` in the `--add-opens` option which is not dependent on the class loader. So you have to decide whether you are actually using modules (in the sense of Java modules) or not.